# Trying to get all xml nodes with SQL Server, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery-sql

I have the following xml in a table cell, in column MyColumn:

```
<BSDL xmlns="..." xmlns:i="...">
  <dateTime>2012-12-30T00:00:00Z</dateTime>
  <dateTime>2013-01-07T00:00:00Z</dateTime>
  <dateTime>2013-01-14T00:00:00Z</dateTime>
  <dateTime>2013-01-21T00:00:00Z</dateTime>
  <dateTime>2013-01-29T00:00:00Z</dateTime>
  <dateTime>2013-02-05T00:00:00Z</dateTime>
  <dateTime>2013-02-12T00:00:00Z</dateTime>
  <dateTime>2013-02-19T00:00:00Z</dateTime>
  <dateTime>2013-03-22T00:00:00Z</dateTime>
  <dateTime>2013-03-29T00:00:00Z</dateTime>
  <dateTime>2013-04-19T00:00:00Z</dateTime>
</BSDL>
```

I'm just trying to query it (get all xml nodes) using:

```
SELECT BSDL.item.value('(dateTime)[1]', 'datetime')
    from [MyTable]
    CROSS APPLY [MyColumn].nodes ('//BSDL') BSDL(item)
```

it yields no result, although my `MyColumn` in `MyTable` has the same number of entries as above, for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's only one `<BSDL>` node - your call to `//BSDL` selects that single node and then `item.value('(dateTime)[1]', 'datetime')` returns the first `<dateTime>` child.

You need to change your XQuery to (use that `xmlns=....` namespace you mention in your sample here):

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('.....' as ns)
SELECT 
    item.value('.', 'datetime')
from 
    dbo.MyTable
CROSS APPLY 
    MyColumn.nodes ('/ns:BSDL/ns:dateTime') BSDL(item)
```

You need to get a list of all `<dateTime>` nodes under `<BSDL>` - then you'll get **all** of them and you can inspect them one by one.

Comment: thanks for your help, still no result though.. I checked the DB,table and column names, and the content a million times.. nothing seems off, and yet no error and no results

Comment: @OrenA: you're also mentioning an `xmlns=.....` in your sample - but you're not showing **what** the XML namespace is. You need to respect that XML namespace, too - see my updated response

Comment: indeed the namespace was the problem. Thanks a lot!